# HeliconTech to deploy .war file on IIS

Tags: java, iis, servlets, helicontech

Sorry, I am a newbie to all this, and have run into trouble, would really appreciate some help.

I am trying to deploy a .war file with a servlet to an IIS server instance. I am trying to use http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/.

The steps I have taken are - put my .war file in folder c:/myapp/mywar.war

Then, I started the IIS Manager, clicked 'Add Web Site' and entered details as below.

[image]

i.e. SiteName:MyLink 
Physical path: c:\myapp

Then, I put a web.config file in c:/myapp/ as
(Note that the file is exactly as below, no fields have been substituted out)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <heliconZoo>
      <application name="jetty.project" >
        <environmentVariables>          
          <!-- A WAR file or start directory to run -->
          <add name="WAR_FILE" value="mywar.war" />
        </environmentVariables>
        </application>
    </heliconZoo>
        <handlers>
          <add name="jetty.project#x86" scriptProcessor="java.jetty" 
            path="*" verb="*" modules="HeliconZoo_x86" 
            preCondition="bitness32" resourceType="Unspecified" 
            requireAccess="Script" />
          <add name="jetty.project#x64" scriptProcessor="java.jetty" 
            path="*" verb="*" modules="HeliconZoo_x64" 
            preCondition="bitness64" resourceType="Unspecified" 
            requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Next, I right-clicked on the site in IIS Manager, and selected restart.I pointed my browser to

```
http://localhost:40/
```

and got an 'Internet Explorer cannot Display webpage' error. What am I doing right/wrong?

Comment: I just happen to have a .war file that needs to be hosted.

Comment: @HighCore at least check the link OP posted where it shows how to configure IIS to support Java web application development through the usage of Jetty.

Comment: @HighCore the question is concrete: HeliconTech (not Microsoft) helps you to deploy Java web applications in IIS but OP has problems to accomplish this task. Your comments are more like rantings about Java technology (not only here but in other questions where I found your comments as well). If you just don't like Java, is ok, but there's no need for the rest of the world (or at least SO readers) to know it. So please, start helping instead of ranting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following "Deploying Java Servlet applications" article, which is rather outdated, please follow these steps instead:

1. Install Helicon Zoo feed for Web Platform Installer as explained on the [Zoo installation page](http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/install.htm)
2. Go to WebPI -> Zoo -> Templates and install either "Java project on Jetty server" or "Java project on Tomcat". There two differs in process model used - Jetty starts separate Java process for each IIS web site while Tomcat uses shared global Tomcat service. It will install all missing dependencies automatically.
3. After installation is completed new web site with installed project will start. Follow instructions on the project home page to start your war file application.